# can not redirect to a deeplink from spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, ionic3

i want to back to my ionic page after executing a spring boot function but i'm get a 404 error : 
**White label Error Page : there was an unexpected type (404) error : /api/paiementenligne/capmission_client://capmission.parent.ma/paiement**

my deeplink in ionic :

```
this.deepLinks.route({'/paiement': PaiementPage,}).subscribe(match => {
  console.log('Successfully matched route', match);
  }, nomatch => {
  console.error('Got a deeplink that didn\'t match', nomatch);
 });
```

my spring boot function :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/paiementenligne")
public class ApiPaiementEnLigne {

    @RequestMapping(value="/ok-fails/mobile",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void paiementIsOkOrNotMobile(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        //some lignes of code
        response.sendRedirect("capmission_client://capmission.parent.ma/paiement");

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try annotating HttpServletResponse with `@Context` (javax) and try to check ?